# Adding North Arrow which adjusts to the map rotation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping, north-arrow

How do you add a working North Arrow into QGIS, one that will rotate if the map is rotated?

I'm aware that in QGIS the North Arrow icon is just an image (Layout -> Add Image/Arrow), what I need to know is how to lock it to the map's rotation. The answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97464/how-to-put-north-arrow-and-scale-on-map-in-composer-in-qgis-2-2-0) states it's possible, but not how.

Googling is failing to bring up any useable answers; the tutorials I'm finding indicate not many people bother with this step.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an option under Item Properties to do this, but it's only available for an Image item, not an Arrow, which may be why you're not seeing it. You need to add your north arrow from an image (Layout -> Add Image). Once you do, there's a checkbox under Image rotation to sync the rotation with your map:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone doing this now on a newer version of QGIS:

After going 'add item', 'add North Arrow', you simply need to go to the item properties, the 'image rotation' dropdown and edit the 'North alignment' option to 'True north'.

[image]